Does the charged defect assume that electrons are localized around the defect? (in VASP DFT)
After searching through various materials, I found that point defect calculations using VASP (DFT calculation) are based on the assumption that the charge of the cell itself is regulated by NELECT, and that the added or reduced charge is a defect. Therefore, I decided that the use of the term “charged defect” presupposes that the charge is localized around the defect.
However, I understood that the resonant defect state in the figure below (1) is a defect with a charge transition level inside the VBM or CBM. In such a defect, only one charge state is stable in the fermi level region inside the entire band gap. This defect formation energy form is reported in many literatures as well as V_I and V_Pb in Figure (2).
However, since this resonant state is not considered to be a localized state, it seems to be in conflict with the basic premise that the defect is charged. I am confused as to how to understand this. I would appreciate your help.

(1) resonant transition level : defect state is located in CBM

(2) Defects like the above are reported in the literature, and here is one example. V_I and V_Pb have charge states of +1 and -1, respectively, across the bandgap. This seems to imply that their charge transition level is inside the CBM or VBM. Since their defect states seem to be delocalized or resonant, can we say that these defects have charge states of +1 or -1?
[reference figure]
(1) https://speakerdeck.com/kavanase/tutorial-understanding-and-modelling-defects-in-semiconductors-with-vasp?slide=27
(2) Xue Haibo, Geert Brocks and Shuxia Tao. Physical Review Materials 5.12 (2021): 125408.

Are you asking whether VASP "knows" a calculation contains a charged defect (no, it doesn't), or whether VASP users typically interpret the simulation results like that?

This question is similar to: Does the charged defect assume that electrons are localized around the defect? (in VASP DFT calculation). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
